# How to prevent console application from unconditionally closing?

Tags: c#, console-application, confirm

**Not** a duplicate of:

- how to remove close button (I want to keep it)
- how to prevent from automatically closing the app (not my problem)

---

And my case is this -- I have a typical console app which when run opens console window. That console window can be closed by clicking on close (x) button. User clicks it, and the app closes.

I would like to detect closing (this could be done with `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`), display yes/no confirmation dialog (with help of WinForms this is not a problem) and if user chooses to stay with app prevent the closing -- and this **is** a problem.

[MSDN for `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016(v=vs.85).aspx) states that no matter what you return from the handler the application will be terminated. Explanation of return values from the handler:

> Return FALSE. If none of the registered handler functions returns
>   TRUE, the default handler **terminates the process**. Return TRUE. In this
>   case, no other handler functions are called and the system **terminates
>   the process**.

Thus I can detect the moment of closing but it is no help in preventing closing.

*In terms of GUI I am looking for event "Closing", not "Closed".*

So how to detect closing of console application, show confirmation dialog and prevent closing (if it is a user choice)?

Comment: Sounds like you shouldn't be running in the console to me and that a GUI app would be more appropriate.

Comment: Check this out, and try the solutions there:  http://geekswithblogs.net/mrnat/archive/2004/09/23/11594.aspx

Comment: @spender, some remarks are predictable ;-).

Comment: @RicardoOrtegaMagaña, that is what I quote (indirectly) -- this is detecting step, useful on its own if I would be sure I want to exit. But I would like to ask user, and I could have to stop closing app (I don't know how).

Comment: Console applications (talking about final products) have limit scope of usage, mostly as command line tools. *"Uncoditional"* closing is not a thing you have to worry/prevent, you can't prevent all means of interrupting anyway (e.g. power failure = no events). Probably telling exactly what your software doing could be more beneficial then asking for help with attempted solution, as people may suggest you something what you haven't thought about.